# trying implement a Custom Encoder in WCF

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, wcf

I have this error: "the auxiliary token signatures that are not expected". The exception occurs because the request is sent without signing , but the response is signed. It seems that .net is waiting for an unsigned response.

I'm Trying to implement a custom Encoder using the [Using MTOM in a WCF custom encoder](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/02/15/using-mtom-in-a-wcf-custom-encoder/)
my code is as follows:

```
   public static consultDocumentPortNameClient CreateDProxy(string url, string username, string password)
    {

        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
        

        var security = TransportSecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement();

        security.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        security.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256;
        security.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
        security.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
        security.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;
        security.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
        security.KeyEntropyMode = SecurityKeyEntropyMode.ServerEntropy;  

        //WSMessageEncoding.Text
        var encoding = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement();
        encoding.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap11;
        encoding.WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        var transport = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
        transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2000000; // 2 megs
        transport.RequireClientCertificate = false;
        transport.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;

    ///***** this the portion of code where I put the 
    binding.Elements.Add(security);
        binding.Elements.Add(encoding);
        binding.Elements.Add(transport);
        binding.Elements.Add(ReadMessage(varxxx, varxxx, varxxx))
```

in the mentioned blog reference I've insert this, that remove the signature:

```
public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer, BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
{
    //Convert the received buffer into a string
    byte[] incomingResponse = buffer.Array;
    incomingResponse = RemoveSignatures(incomingResponse);
    ........
```

and that class include the follow method:

```
private byte[] RemoveSignatures(byte[] stream)
{
    string stream2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream);           
    stream2 = stream2.Replace("\0", "");

    Regex x = new Regex("(\\<SOAP-ENV:Header\\>)(.*?)(\\</SOAP-ENV:Header\\>)");            
    string repl = "";
    stream2 = x.Replace(stream2, "$1" + repl + "$3");
    byte[] streamNuevo = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stream2);

    return streamNuevo;
}
```

where should I implement this method (--- ReadMessage (varxxx, varxxx, varxxx) ---) with the respective parameters?

I'm a newbie with wcf

Comment: Did you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to see what response you actually got.  Check the response statues to see if you got a 200 DONE or something else.  Also make sure you download the entire code in the link "here" which is a zip file with the entire project.  You may also be timing out with no response which indicates your request was bad.

Comment: @jdweng yep! I did! i used fiddler and the response was 200 well done! but In a try catch, writes me in a logger "the auxiliary token signatures that are not expected" it seems that dot net is waiting for an unsigned response. My idea is to eliminate the signature in the response; so what I want is.. that, it does not write that kind of error!

Comment: Once you get a 200 DONE there is no more data.  If Net is waiting then maybe it is expecting http 1.1 (chunk mode) instead of 1.0 (stream mode).  You are looking for security which is https but it looks like you are getting non secure http.